# WPF: The ScrollBar is not activated on ScrollViewer

Tags: .net, wpf, scaletransform

**WPF**
Why the ScrollBar is not activated on ScrollViewer when I zoom in?

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication4.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="356" Width="804">
    <Grid>
        <ScrollViewer
            PreviewMouseWheel="ScrollViewer_PreviewMouseWheel" 
            VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"
            HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible">
            <Canvas>
                <Canvas.LayoutTransform>
                    <TransformGroup>
                        <ScaleTransform x:Name="scaleTransform"/>
                    </TransformGroup>
                </Canvas.LayoutTransform>
                <TextBlock Canvas.Left="34" Canvas.Top="47" Name="textBlock1" Text="TK QSDFWPO Aàâéèêëîïôùûüÿçæœ; BLA BLA BLA...... " />
                <TextBlock Canvas.Left="310" Canvas.Top="46" Name="textBlock4" Text="TK QSDFWPO Aàâéèêëîïôùûüÿçæœ; BLA BLA BLA...... " />
                <TextBlock Canvas.Left="188" Canvas.Top="157" Name="textBlock11" Text="TK QSDFWPO Aàâéèêëîïôùûüÿçæœ; BLA BLA BLA...... " />
            </Canvas>
        </ScrollViewer>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

CS:

```
private void ScrollViewer_PreviewMouseWheel(object sender, MouseWheelEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Delta > 0)
        scaleTransform.ScaleY =
            scaleTransform.ScaleX += 0.1;
    else
        scaleTransform.ScaleY =
            scaleTransform.ScaleX -= 0.1;
}
```

Why the ScrollBar is not activated when I zoom in?

Answer (score 1):

Canvas doesn't resize to its contents. You should use another panel. Grid for example:

```
<ScrollViewer
    PreviewMouseWheel="ScrollViewer_PreviewMouseWheel" 
    VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"
    HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.LayoutTransform>
            <TransformGroup>
                <ScaleTransform x:Name="scaleTransform"/>
            </TransformGroup>
        </Grid.LayoutTransform>
        <TextBlock Margin="34,47" Name="textBlock1" Text="TK QSDFWPO Aàâéèêëîïôùûüÿçæœ; BLA BLA BLA...... " />
        <TextBlock Margin="310,46" Name="textBlock4" Text="TK QSDFWPO Aàâéèêëîïôùûüÿçæœ; BLA BLA BLA...... " />
        <TextBlock Margin="188,157" Name="textBlock11" Text="TK QSDFWPO Aàâéèêëîïôùûüÿçæœ; BLA BLA BLA...... " />
    </Grid>
</ScrollViewer>
```

also I think you need to mark event as handled to prevent vertical scroll:

```
private void ScrollViewer_PreviewMouseWheel(object sender, MouseWheelEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Delta > 0)
        scaleTransform.ScaleY =
            scaleTransform.ScaleX += 0.1;
    else
        scaleTransform.ScaleY =
            scaleTransform.ScaleX -= 0.1;

    e.Handled = true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to set Width and Height for it (it will not work in Auto)

i.e.:
`<Canvas Width="250" Height="235">`

tried on mind and it worked, good luck!

Comment: yeah, my own response does this think in the same direction... thank you

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned Marat, the Canvas does not change its size after its content.
But we can force it like this, naming the parent Window as  by eg."myWpfApplication4.MainWindow" and:

```
<Canvas
  Height="{Binding ElementName=myWpfApplication4.MainWindow, Path=ActualHeight}"
  Width="{Binding ElementName=myWpfApplication4.MainWindow, Path=ActualWidth}">
```